# Flex layout issue in md:flex-col class in Next.js project with Tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

```
<div className="flex justify-center md:justify-end gap-4 bg-red-300">
        <Select
          onValueChange={(value) => handleSearchParams("category", value)}
        >
          <SelectTrigger className="w-[180px]">
            <SelectValue placeholder="Category" />
          </SelectTrigger>
          <SelectContent>
            <SelectItem value="all">All</SelectItem>
            {categories?.map((item) => (
              <SelectItem key={item.id} value={item.name}>
                {item.name}
              </SelectItem>
            ))}
          </SelectContent>
        </Select>

        <Select onValueChange={(value) => handleSearchParams("sort", value)}>
          <SelectTrigger className="w-[180px]">
            <SelectValue placeholder="Sort" />
          </SelectTrigger>
          <SelectContent>
            <SelectItem value="asc">
              <span className="font-semibold">price:</span> asc
            </SelectItem>
            <SelectItem value="desc">
              <span className="font-semibold">price:</span> desc
            </SelectItem>
            <SelectItem value="latest">latest</SelectItem>
            <SelectItem value="oldest">oldest</SelectItem>
          </SelectContent>
        </Select>
      </div>
```

I'm facing a peculiar problem with the md:justify-end class in my Next.js project using Tailwind CSS. When I apply this class to a div, it doesn't seem to have any effect on the layout. However, if I use justify-end without the md: prefix, the layout behaves as expected.

this is with md:justify-end [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDPBZ.png)

this is without md: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVjJX.png)

in other projects everything works fine. Does anyone have any ideas on how to repair it?

here is my tailwind.ts config:

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss"

const config = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    ],
  prefix: "",
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1400px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        border: "hsl(var(--border))",
        input: "hsl(var(--input))",
        ring: "hsl(var(--ring))",
        background: "hsl(var(--background))",
        foreground: "hsl(var(--foreground))",
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--primary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--primary-foreground))",
        },
        secondary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--secondary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))",
        },
        destructive: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--destructive))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))",
        },
        muted: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--muted))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--muted-foreground))",
        },
        accent: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--accent))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--accent-foreground))",
        },
        popover: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--popover))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--popover-foreground))",
        },
        card: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--card))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--card-foreground))",
        },
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        'heroImg': "url('@/assets/heroImg.jpg)",
      },
      borderRadius: {
        lg: "var(--radius)",
        md: "calc(var(--radius) - 2px)",
        sm: "calc(var(--radius) - 4px)",
      },
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: "0" },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: "0" },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate")],
} satisfies Config

export default config
```

Comment: Consider checking the file that the code is in is covered by the `content` file globs. Also, consider checking the browser viewport is sufficiently large to match the `md:` media queries. Also consider checking there is no other CSS that could be interferring.